# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm trying to fetch usersList using [axios](/questions/tagged/axios) api

But I got an error below:

How to solve this problem?

I attached my code

I think `renderUsers` function has a problem...

[image]

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchUsers } from '../actions';

class UsersList extends Component {
    componentDidMount(){
        // this.props.fetchUsers();


        console.log("It called....")
    }

    renderUsers(){
        console.log("renderUsers()")

        return this.props.users.map(user => {
            return <li key={user.id}>{user.name}</li>;
        })
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                Here's a big list of users:
                <ul>{this.renderUsers()}</ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return { users: state.users };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchUsers })(UsersList);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.props.users` is `undefined` before it is an Array. You should add a check before using [Array.map()][1]

```
renderUsers(){
    console.log("renderUsers()");
    const { users } = this.props;

    return Array.isArray(users) && users.map(u=> <li key={u.id}>{u.name}</li>);
}
```

or add a `defaultProp` in your component

```
class UsersList extends Component {
    static defaultProps = {
        users: []
    }
}
```

Comment: OP isn't using TypeScript?

Comment: @Colin you're right! I totally didn't notice that. Just updated the answer with an example instead

Answer (score 2):

You first remove comment from `this.props.fetchUsers();` in componentDidMount so it could fire API and get the response.

Now component will render(at least first time) even before we get response from API. in that case `this.props.users` is undefined.

So check if `this.props.users` before you map it.

```
renderUsers(){
    console.log("renderUsers()")

    return this.props.users && this.props.users.map(user => {
        return <li key={user.id}>{user.name}</li>;
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's likely that in your parent component, you have something like: `let users;`. This means it's being passed as `undefined` and messing up your `map()`. So, try declaring it as `let user = {}` instead.